# Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: invalid json token when authenticating to Google Calendar

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am a student and now it's the final stage of my final project. I am working with PHP. The documentation that I worked with is: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php

**My problem is that the Token returns NULL.**

**The error I get is:**
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: invalid json token in C:\wamp64\www\MarryMe\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php:420
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp64\www\MarryMe\insertevent.php(26): Google_Client->setAccessToken(NULL)
#1 C:\wamp64\www\MarryMe\insertevent.php(66): getClient()
#2 {main}
thrown in C:\wamp64\www\MarryMe\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php on line 420

**Here is my code:**

````
require_once('./conection/init.php');
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName('MarryMe');
  $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
  $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

  // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
  // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
  // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
  // time.
  $tokenPath = 'token.json';
  if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
  }

  // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
    if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
      $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    } else {
      if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
        // Request authorization from the user.
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header("location: $authUrl");
      } else {
        $code = $_GET['code'];
        $authCode = trim($code);
        var_dump($authCode);
        // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
        var_dump($accessToken);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        // Check to see if there was an error.
        if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
          throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
        }
      }
    }
    // Save the token to a file.
    if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
  return $client;
}



// Get the API client and construct the service object.

$client = getClient();

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 50,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => true,
  'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();


$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' =>  $_SESSION['name'],
  'location' => ' ',
  'description' => $_SESSION['description'],
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => $_SESSION['start_date'],
    'timeZone' => 'UTC',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => $_SESSION['due_date'],
    'timeZone' => 'UTC',
  ),

  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);

header("location:./includes/tasksProcess/tasks.php");


//end of insert event ```
````

Comment: So did you check whether `file_get_contents($tokenPath)` returns a value? Did you check whether json_decode fails, and what the error was (use json_last_error_msg() to find out)? Do you have general error reporting switched on so any file warnings would appear. Do some basic debugging please (because we can't do it for you).

Comment: You created a new project up on Google cloud console and created credentials for that project.  You should have downloaded a clientsecrete.json file what type of credentials did you create?   The tutorial you are following is for an installed application you appear to have made a lot of changes which would make it more of a web application.   What are you trying to do here?

Comment: it's really for a web application and in the credential there is the client secret

Comment: That's not what I asked did you create an Desktop app client on google Cloud console as instructed by the sample you are using or a Web application client which is what your code is going to need if its a web application?   https://youtu.be/eiiktPs5z50  After double checking that you created a web client.  I would also double check that the application can actually find  credentials.json

Comment: @DaimTo - dont get a customer facing support role ;)

Comment: @Datadimension Im just a lowly software developer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `__DIR__ .` is before where your credentials is instantiated so that the function knows where to look for the json file:

so it should look like this

`$client->setAuthConfig( __DIR__ . 'credentials.json');`